# Bootstrap responsive layout issues - Nav disappears and div overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am using Twitter bootstrap for my portfolio site. The fluid layout seems to work up to a certain point, but there are a few issues with the home page.

1. Once I go smaller than about 997px, the nav menu disappears entirely. It almost looks like it drops down below the header bar and is hidden, but I can't seem to get it to show. It should actually switch to the mobile menu and remain in the upper right corner.
2. Also once you get down to smaller screen sizes, the "About Me" and "Contact" sections of the index page overlap each other. I'm sure this has to do with my structure somehow, but cannot find the problem.

Any bootstrap experts know what might be causing these issues?

Here is a link to the test version of the site. http://theiamzone.com/kyle_hagler/portfolio-site

Answer (score 0):

From the source code I view from the site,
I Found out that you lacked of jquery file.

> `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">`

Put it and see if the dropdown work.

And for the About Us and Contact Us part.

A method you can try is put container to wrap them all, read from here for more information. 
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

From my point of view in about us section, try no to wrap the 2 span 6 column, 
Use the following code instead.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
       <div class="span6"></div>
       <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same situation happen on the contact us section, 
the css class aren't assigned for them to work.

Comment: Realized I had set fixed heights on some divs which was causing the overlaps as the content started to overflow the divs. That issue has been fixed. Only real problem now is that with the navigation.

Also, jQuery is there on line 24
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: include the bootstrap-collapse.js
or you just include the jquery.js provided by bootstrap.